# Faucet dripping only when water main shut off

Tags: faucet

The city responded to a water main break down the block last night. When they shut off the water to repair it, a bathroom faucet started to drip at the spout.  It was more like a thin stream/dripping.  I opened and closed the faucet; no difference in the stream open or closed.  This is a second story faucet.  When opening other faucets on that level there was no pressure at all.  The water supply is back on now and the faucet is not dripping.
I figure this is an early sign of something.  The fixture is about 25 years old.  Could you please comment on what could be wrong and what I should do about it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

Single handle faucets or washer less actually use the pressure as part of the mechanism to stop the flow, when the pressure is reduced two far some start dripping. I usually have standard rubber washers and several sizes of O-rings for washerless faucets to replace when they start dripping, if after the pressure is restored the drip has stopped I would not worry until it starts dripping with normal pressure. Usually once a washerless starts dripping you have months to repair.